# Increase Outer Container Width

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I'm building a WordPress theme on Bourbon and Neat. I am using Codekit to manage/compile SASS. I looked at the bourbon Docs and added this to my variables.scss file:

```
$max-width: em(1200) !default;
```

After this complies, however, the width of the outer container is still 1088px.

I also noticed the $visual-grid variables don't work either. Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the `!default;` so:

```
$max-width: em(1200);
```

Fixes my issue.